# Make a AJAX HTTPS POST Request with parameters in header

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC and I would like to make a https post request with ajax (with the parameters in the header) to a method in my controller. By now I did a get http with the parameters in the url. Like the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "api/login"
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: {
          dir: "tokens",
          param1: param1,
          param2: param2
        },
        success: function (data) {
        ...
        }
)};
```

Then on server side i have

```
public String Get(String dir, String usr, String pswd) 
{
 ...
}
```

I have no idea how to convert this into a post https with parameters in the header..

Answer (score 1):

Since I want my parameters in the header I think I should do it in this way

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/login",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Usr", user);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Pswd", password);
        },
        ...
        )};
```

And then on the controller i have

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public String checkUsrPswd() // Post() per l'username e la password
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headerUsr = Request.Headers.GetValues("Usr");
        String usr = headerUsr.FirstOrDefault();
        IEnumerable<string> headerPswd = Request.Headers.GetValues("Pswd");
        String pswd = headerPswd.FirstOrDefault();
        ...
     }
```

where i read the header values.

The thing is now that i have two post request where i put the parameters in the header but i am not able to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

Just add following line to your ajax call arguments

type: "POST"

anyway typing "mvc post ajax" could give you the same answer ;)

Comment: yes and how about the https and the parameters in the header?

Comment: Don't want to mislead you, but you need to do that call within https page. That's all, and probably you are not able to do call from normal http page.

Answer (score 0):

set the `contentType: application/json` and `type : post`.

Comment: Expanding why and how this solves the OP question will him/her deciding whether this is a good answer (or not).

Comment: because the OP is capable of posting data, preferably setting the contentType value to help detemine the type he is sending.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
         url: "api/login",
         type: 'POST',
         data: "dir=" +"tokens" + "&usr=" + param1 + "&pswd=" + param2,
         success: function (data) {
```

Comment: Replace Its And Check  Your  Action.